# How do I change row in automated response with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have problem with my automated response that client sees when he submits a form from my site.

The pages are in three languages and the "thank you message" in the automated response is in three languages.

However, I have tried different methods to make these three short different lauguage messages to be displayed on three different rows, but I have not found the answer. Now the message looks like this:

**Viesti lähetetty! Success! Meddelandet är skickat!**
Olen yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani! I will be in contact shortly! Jag är i kontakt så fort som möjligt!

I would like it to be like this:

1. Viesti lähetetty!
2. Success!
3. Meddelandet är skickat!
4. Olen yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani!
5. I will be in contact shortly!
6. Jag är i kontakt så fort som möjligt!

I used a nubered list here, but I only want messages to be in different rows.
I have tried /n and different methods but noting seems to change the row correctly. These automated replies are on js file that is called TMform.js

The part of the js file where all the language answers are looks like this:

```
form
                            .removeClass(opt.processingClass)
                            .addClass(opt.successClass)


                        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Viesti lähetetty! Success!  Meddelandet är skickat!')
                        modal.find('.modal-body').text('Olen yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani!\r I will be in contact shortly!\r Jag är i kontakt så fort som möjligt!')


                        setTimeout(function(){
                            form
                            .removeClass(opt.successClass)
                            .trigger('reset')
                        },opt.successShowDelay)
                    }else{                          
                        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Error!')
                        modal.find('.modal-body').html(e)

                        form
```

There is another file that somehow also controls the form file which name is modal.js

If someone knows how to do the row change and format js files that dispaly messages, it would be a big help.
The form is easily tested by filling in some data and submitting it, then the thank you message that I want to display differently is seen.

Comment: Did you try `<br/>` instead of `\n`?

Comment: Yes, but <br/> doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `.modal-body` and `.modal-title` classes are on div's, you need to append a `<p>`tag to the div instead of just setting the text like this:

```
$('.modal-title').append('<p>MESSAGE</p>');
$('.modal-body').append('<p>BODY</p>');
```

Comment: Yes but the message is currently fetched inside the jquery file, do you mean I should remove the message from there and move it to the HTML instead?

Comment: No, just use the snippet above to append the new tag to the element in the HTML file from the JavaScript file.

Comment: To be clear about this all, do you mean that I shoud paste the above lines into my TMForm.js file, so the result would be like this:                  modal.find ('.modal-title').append('<p>Viesti lähetetty! Success!  Meddelandet är skickat!</p>');                                                                                                        Then the second part of the message comes under this one, or am I misundertanding you complitely?

Comment: After these tweaks, I added <br> tags to change row, but here is the result: MODAL TITLE
VIESTI LÄHETETTY! SUCCESS! MEDDELANDET ÄR SKICKAT!
VIESTI LÄHETETTY! SUCCESS! MEDDELANDET ÄR SKICKAT!
Kiitos, viestisi on lähetetty onnistuneesti! Olen yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani.
len yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani! I will be in contact shortly! Jag är i kontakt så fort som möjligt!
len yhteydessä heti tiedot luettuani! I will be in contact shortly! Jag är i kontakt så fort som möjligt!

Comment: After these tweaks, I added <br> tags inside the <p></p> tags to change row, but the result is a total mess and no row change happens. I have asked this from other forums also but nobody seems to be able to give an accurate answer.